# How to bind to selection from autocomplete?

Tags: jquery

I want to bind to the event after selection element from autocomplete

Here is my script with autocomplete:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = '@Url.Action("TagName", "Tag")';
                $('#TagModel_Name').autocomplete(url, {
                    minChars: 1,
                    multiple: true,
                    formatResult: function (row) {
                        return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

And I want add some label at bottom page with text of selected item.

So :

1. I type a to '#TagModel_Name "a"
2. I select "austria"
3. now text of '#TagModel_Name i "austria" 4. event fires, and there would be method like

   var newlabel=$'(' $selected_tag')
    $("'#TagModel_Name:last").after($newlabel);

I'm using

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js")"></script>
```

and asp.net-mvc 3 razor

Sorry for my bad english. I hope you understand what I want.

Best regards

Comment: What's the url of the autocomplete plugin you're using?

Comment: It's name of controller and its action - it's mvc 3 razor

Answer (score 0):

You should use the select event. Something like this might work: (i don't understand what exactly you want to do afterwards, if you provide your markup i might help)

```
        $('#TagModel_Name').autocomplete(url, {
                minChars: 1,
                multiple: true,
                formatResult: function (row) {
                    return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
                },
                select: function(event, ui){
                    //here ui.item refers to the selected item.
                      var div = $('<div>', {class: 'tag'});
                      div.html(ui.item.label);
                      $('#demo').after(div);
                }
            });
        });
```

EDIT - i provided a basic solution for what you asked in the comment: look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/e97QP/

Comment: I want the same feature like at stackoverflow when you're adding tag to the question. You select tag, and below you get label with text the same as selected tag:)

Comment: I've added alert(event.toString()); and                       alert(ui.toString()); inside your method and there is a silence:/ no error in firebug and no alert

Comment: I think that we different jquery plugins because your example without any modification(I've created new site) doesn't work at all :/

Comment: Have you looked at the fiddle?It has no styling because no jquery-ui css has loaded but it's working. my example up here is based on the markup of the fiddle where a div with id='demo surrounds the autocomplete input

Comment: @Nicola: I believe the OP is using the plugin found here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions (which is deprecated), and you're using jQueryUI's autocomplete widget.